# Boundedness of a Continuous Function with a Bounded Derivative

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ be a continuous function which has a derivative $f'$ that is defined and also continuous on $[0, 1]$. Suppose $|f'(x)| < 1 \,\, \forall x \in [0, 1]$. I'm trying to show that there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$, with $M < 1$, such that for all $x, y \in [0, 1]$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x - y|$.

The desired form has some semblance to parts of the mean value theorem; in particular, for all $x, y \in [0, 1]$, $|f(x) - f(y)|  = f'(c)|x - y|$ for some $c \in (0, 1)$. Can we immediately conclude that given $|f'(x)| < 1 \,\, \forall x \in [0, 1]$, we have such an $M < 1$, or is a more involved effort required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|=1$, then a convergent sequence $(x_{n})\subseteq[0,1]$ is such that $|f'(x_{n})|\rightarrow\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|$, say, $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, then by continuity of $f'$, $|f'(x)|=1$, a contradiction.

So you can take $M=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|<1$.